# How to create two auto increment columns using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, exception, syntax-error, liquibase

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: ...
      author: ...
      preConditions:
        - onError: MARK_RAN
        - not:
            - tableExists:
                tableName: ORDERS
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: ORDERS
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: ID
                  type: INT
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
              - column:
                  name: ID_USER
                  type: INT
              ...

        - sql:
            "DELIMITER $$
             CREATE FUNCTION autoInc ()
                 RETURNS INT(10)
                 BEGIN
                     DECLARE getCount INT(10);

                     SET getCount = (
                         SELECT COUNT(USER_ID)
                         FROM ORDERS) + 1;

                     RETURN getCount;
                 END$$
             DELIMITER ;"
```

I am using this approach. When I will insert new entry in orders it should increment user_id too. Because I need user_id as another auto increment column. I am using Liquibase migration to create this table, but I get an error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE FUNCTION autoInc () RETURNS INT(10) BEGIN DECLARE getCount I' at line 1
    ...
```

Maybe, I do something wrong?

Comment: MySQL does not support multiple auto-increment columns per table. As far as I know only PostgreSQL does. I don't see why you would need this, but if you really do, the options I can see are creating an "generated" column with some generation logic, or use a trigger to populate the value of the second column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of problems with your approach.

First, `DELIMITER` is a [built-in command of the mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html), it is not recognized by the MySQL Server's SQL parser. Also, I wonder why you are not using https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/pro/create-function.html

Second, your method of simulating a second auto-increment is flawed. It suffers from a race condition, because if more than one concurrent transaction is inserting a row, they will both get the same result from your SELECT COUNT(*) query, and therefore both attempt to insert the same value for the user_id.

The real auto-increment mechanism in MySQL works outside of transaction scope, so multiple sessions are assured to read the same increment value per table. There is also a brief table-lock while each session increments the table's counter.

To make your function safe from race conditions, you would have to lock the table, to ensure that only one session at a time can read the value.

Third, the auto-increment should be based on `MAX(USER_ID)`, not `COUNT(USER_ID)` if you're going to calculate the next higher value. If you were to delete a few rows from the table, then `COUNT(USER_ID)` would generate a value lower than the max value.

Lastly, I can't understand why you would want to make user_id auto-increment at all for an orders table. You would really want *every* order to generate a new user_id? Aren't user_id's supposed to reference a currently existing user?